# react-hot-loader в Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp

Добрый день! Стоит задача писать проект на ReactJS в Gulp.
Пытаюсь найти хоть какую нибудь информацию по hot load для Gulp и пока ничего не нашел. Кто может подсказать где по читать или дать конфиги?

Comment: Можно ведь запускать Webpack из Gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `gulp` нет `react-hot-loader`. Думаю, большинство вам скажет, что лучше использовать только webpack для сборки проектов с реактом. Но, если вам все-таки хочется `gulp`, то можно сделать так: замените ваш таск для сборки js на таск, запускающий `webpac`k, потом вам понадобится `webpack-dev-server` для организации быстрой перезагрузки и `webpack-hot-middleware` для запоминания текущего стейтов, а то после каждой быстрой перезагрузки вы будите проваливаться в начальный стейт и долго кликать до нужного состояния. У меня это выглядит примерно так:

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src(webpackConfig.entry)
    .pipe($.webpack(webpackConfig))
    .pipe(isProduction ? $.uglify() : $.util.noop())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe($.size({ title : 'js' }));
});

gulp.task("webpack-dev-server", function(callback) {
  var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
  var myConfig = Object.create(webpackConfig);
  myConfig.devtool = "eval";
  myConfig.debug = true;

  var app = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(myConfig), {
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./build",
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: {
      colors: true
    }
  });

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

  app.listen(port, "localhost", function(err) {
    if(err) throw new gutil.PluginError("webpack-dev-server", err);
    gutil.log("[webpack-dev-server]", "http://localhost:" + port +  "/build/");
  });
});
```

Webpack занимается исключительно js, а все остальное обрабатывает и собирает gulp.